Issue with Nginx Not Terminating Properly
I am facing an issue with Nginx on my Windows system. Here's the sequence of events:
I started Nginx using the command line, but the terminal froze, so I closed it.
I reopened the command line and started Nginx again using start nginx, and it seemed to work fine.
When I used nginx -s stop to stop the server, I found that localhost was still accessible.
In Task Manager, I noticed that there were still nginx.exe processes running. Every time I ended these processes, new ones would appear automatically.
At this point, I thought having a few unused processes wouldn't matter much, so I continued learning Nginx. However, when I tried to deploy a static site, I couldn't display my blog on localhost. Even after correctly copying the files to the html directory, it still showed the old welcome page, which I had already deleted. I also cleared my browser cache.
I am unsure how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried using the command taskkill /f /t /im nginx.exe to terminate all Nginx processes, but the processes kept reappearing. I even tried to delete ngnix to stop these pthread but fialed too.

I have solved this problem.

Open cmd as administrator
sc query nginx
sc stop nginx
sc delete nginx

